# Limiting the result of intersection between two sets in Redis efficiently

Tags: redis

I have an exam software system and one of the features is to show students random questions from a huge set given that the question has never been show to the student before. I'm using redis to implement it, so I made two types sets in my Redis DB, the first one is the question bank and then each user has a his own set of previously viewed questions that gets updated after the user sees a question in an exam.

However, in order to make the requirement, I need to find 10 question from the questions bank for each exam that the user has never seen before. I thought of using:

```
SDIFFSTORE nextQuestionsToShow questionBank userQuestionsSet
SRANDMEMBER nextQuestionsToShow 10
```

and after processing the result, I delete the produced set nextQuestionsToShow.

However, I think this is inefficient (time and memory wise) since it's an anytime online exam system for users during the day, and the question bank has a huge amount of questions per category (some categories has over 100K questions), and this means that the difference is a huge set for each user that has to be stored to only select 10 random questions. So is there a more efficient way to select 10 random questions from the question bank that the user hasn't answered before? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using SET to store `userQuestionsSet` and `questionBank`, you can use bitmap (Redis STRING) to store these two sets. Then you can use the `BITOP` to efficiently get the difference between two bitmap.

**UPDATE**

First of all, you need to give each question to a unique number. Then use a bitmap to store the `userQuestionsSet` and `questionBank`. Say, you have the following questions in bank: *1: question1*, *2: question2*, *3: question3*, *4: question4*, *5: question5*. And user has already viewed *question3*:

```
// initialize question bank: 00111110
SETBIT question-bank 1 1
SETBIT question-bank 2 1
...
SETBIT question-bank 5 1

// user has viewed question3: 00001000
SETBIT user 3 1
```

Get the difference between question bank and user viewed questions:

```
// XOR to get the difference: 00111110 XOR 00001000
BITOP XOR result question-bank user

// 00110110
// questions not viewed: 1, 2, 4, 5
GET result
```

When you GET the binary string stored in result, you can scan the string and randomly get 10 questions for the user.

**NOTE**

You should be careful that `SETBIT` might be an expensive operation, and you'd better pre-allocate memory for these bitmaps. See the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/setbit)'s WARNING part for detail.

Comment: thx @for_stack .. but can you please show me an example of redis commands to do it .. also, after the difference how can I get 10 random questions from the difference?